# Scroll other views along with RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, scrollview, android-recyclerview

I have a relative layout and that layout has a sliding tab layout which has 3 fragments which have one reyclerview each in them . Now the problem i am facing is that is that i have an image and some other views above the sliding tab , when i scroll the recycler view inside the view pager all other views above them dont move as a result i dont have enough room for the recycler view . What i would like to happen is that when i scroll the recycler view i want all other views to scroll as well .
 
***ALSO I DONT WANT TO USE A CO ORDINATOR LAYOUT***
Here is my basic XML Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <!--View above the tabs containing the heders etc-->
    </RelativeLayout>


    <com.example.skmishra.plates.Library.SlidingTabLayout
android:id="@+id/tabs"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_below="@+id/innerColor"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<!--For elevation add here-->


</com.example.skmishra.plates.Library.SlidingTabLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_below="@id/tabs"
android:id="@+id/viewPager"
android:fillViewport="false">

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Please help me , thank you for answering !!

Comment: take a look at Co-ordinator layout.

Comment: As i mentioned i dont want to use a co ordinator layout

Comment: How can i implement it without that

Comment: why is that? anything that prevents you from using co-ordinator layout?

Comment: Because it scrolls even when not needed , which leaves empty space behind

Comment: Hope that makes sense